# How to set the arrangement of the folders that I want?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, web-part

I would like to create a new folder which named 'DI' and I want to put at the first which us above "DS'" folder. How to set the arrangement of the folders that I want?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click the "New" link, then select "Folder" and assign the desired name. By default, folders will appear in alphabetical order.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is it possible to change the default if i dont want them appear in alphabetical order?

Comment: If DI is above DS, then that is alphabetical, so what's the problem? If you want a custom order you may need to adjust the content type, add a custom column, assign values to the custom column, create a view that sorts by that custom column. Or, create folder names that start a sort string, like "001-Bla", "002-Foo", 003-Bar". In any case, if you want something different from the default it will be work and it will most likely be ugly and/or hard to maintain.